# Jenkins intermittent git connectivity error

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gitlab

I have a Jenkins job that 99% of the time runs without issue but occasionally I am getting an error generated by the Git plugin when trying to fetch.  The Git repo in question is hosted in GitLab.

The source of this error could be Jenkins, network connectivity or GitLab.

**My question is has anyone seen a similar issue using Jenkins with Git hosted in GitLab or otherwise?**

Stack Trace (redacted for security reasons):

```
Building remotely on [MACHINE_NAME] (build) in workspace c:\workspace\location
 > C:\location\of\git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\location\of\git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@git.<gitlab-server>:My/project.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@git.<gitlab-server>:My/project.git
 > C:\location\of\git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > C:\location\of\git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@git.<gitlab-server>:My/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@git.<gitlab-server>:My/project.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:797)
    ...
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\location\of\git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@git.<gitlab-server>:My/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1752)
    ...
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:795)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: null
Warning: you have no plugins providing access control for builds, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Edit (based on down-vote)**
Research carried out so far (I am running the Jenkins job on a regular schedule):

1. Modified Jenkins to read ssh private key from specific file on the machine Jenkins runs on - Error observed intermittently
2. Copy and pasted ssh private key directly into Jenkins (in case of a file
   access permission issue with 1.) - Error observed intermittently
3. Git command run as a scheduled job on the windows machine on which Jenkins runs (attempt to eliminate Jenkins as the source of the issue) - awaiting outcome...

If point 3 produces the error then I can be quite sure it is a GitLab or Network Connectivity issue.  If it does not, then I can be sure it's a Jenkins issue.  If anyone has noticed this issue before I'd be grateful to know how they solved it.

**Update (based on research results)**

The job referred to in point 3 above was run hourly over the weekend.  No errors were observed.  The Jenkins job was also run hourly over the weekend and two errors were observed.  **This supports the theory that the issue is with the Jenkins Git plugin.**

Comment: you ever get close to a solution?  We see this kind of thin with github.  Seems to be drive by crunch periods (demo days) with nothing useful in the logs.

Comment: @PeterKahn - Unfortunately, I didn't get any closer to a solution and I don't work for the same company so I'm not investigating it anymore.  Given the results of experiment 3, it did suggest the issue is with the Jenkins Git plugin. I remember the issue I had seemed pretty random with no identifiable pattern.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the issue was due to the "MaxStartups" directive in sshd, which specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated connections to the SSH daemon (see man sshd_config for details).

When many Jenkins jobs are running concurrently, this may results in many concurrent unauthenticated connections to the SSH daemon, in which case sshd will start dropping connections. You can set the "MaxStartups" directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to increase number of concurrent unauthenticated connections at which sshds will start dropping connections (defaults to 10).

From this related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/924058/jenkins-occasionally-fails-to-clone-fetch

Comment: I changed to this as the correct answer because from the serverfault link this looks like exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

On the Jenkins Server run [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and look for *orphaned* Git Processes. Eg with SourceTree:

[image]

## Solution:

**There will probably be a few Git.exe processes running wild, kill them, kill process tree. One at a time, it's important you try to narrow down and share your findings :)**

To test if this works, back in Jenkins retype the git repo path (that causes a refresh) and then you wont see the error trying to connect to Git.

<sub>You could probably use Task Manager instead of ProcessExplorer, I find its better to diagnose with ProcessExplorer and in general with SysInternal tools.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I can't verify that this works since I'm no longer working on this project.  However, I'll mark as the correct answer since it has worked for you.

Comment: I do appreciate your response but, for people searching this in the future, I unmarked this and marked the other answer as correct because this one is really a process to discover the problem, whereas the other is most likely to be the solution.

Comment: @Stuart no problem mate, the other answer sounds applicable to what I faced.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, someone at the company had edited the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file and added a custom ProxyCommand. I commented out that line, and it worked.